# What is the difference between TPL dataflow and Akka.net?

Tags: .net, akka, task-parallel-library, actor, tpl-dataflow

I have worked with TPL dataflow. Really liked it. I had heard the term Akka many times from my java/scala friends so I tried to read about it and found out that akka has a .net port too. Great. When I continued reading about what akka is, I was surprised to see that it sounds exactly like TPL dataflow.

So coming to my question, what is the difference between TPL dataflow and Akka.net ?

When to chose what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Akka is an actor based model, and so is TPL Dataflow. As the latter is described as *"This dataflow model promotes actor-based programming by providing in-process message passing for coarse-grained dataflow and pipelining tasks."* I think there should be an emphasis on *in-process*, as Akka allows you to create remote actors, which don't necessarily reside inside the same process.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a piece of interesting information related to the comparison of Akka.NET and TPL Dataflow, which both are actor-based:

http://blog.i3arnon.com/2016/05/23/tpl-dataflow/

> For actor model have you checked out Akka.net? It is a port of the
> Akka framework from Java\Scala that seems to have built up a pretty
> strong community. Just curious how TPL Dataflow compares?
>
> I've actually talked about it with one of the owners, Aaron Stannard,
> at .NET Fringe. He said their initial implementation actually used TPL
> Dataflow underneath. I think TPL Dataflow is more of a library while
> AKKA.NET is a framework. TPL Dataflow is for in-process pipelines
> while AKKA is a distributed system infrastructure though they share
> the same mindset.

Aaron is the co-founder and CTO of Petabridge, as well as the co-founder of the Akka.NET open-source project.

Comment: interesting indeed